# How to update "static_path" and "xstatic_url" on the fly in tornado?

Tags: python, web, webserver, tornado

I'm new to Tornado, and trying to understand how can i update the `static_path` **on the fly**.
(The Xstatic will be similar i guess)

For example:

```
Application([
    ('/static1/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path='static1')),
    ('/static2/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path='static2')),
])
```

I want to be able to update the path on the fly, **inside** the implementation of one of those Handlers.

Is that even possible?
I know there are tools like `static_url_prefix` and update the `static_path` via settings of tornado.
But can i do it on the fly? **during execution of one the Handlers**.

**My usecase: Why do i need it?**

When i am connecting via proxy server to load the web page of the application, there is a header of "/proxy/aHR0cHM6Ly8xMC4xLjMuMTAwOjQ0Mw==/" added to the URL in the browser, so it probably changes the relative path and i need to adjust the location of the static sources accordingly.
(currently the html page cannot find the static sources when proxy used)

**The problem:**

I cannot know if there is a proxy or not,when tornado is first loaded.
I know that only later when one of the handlers catches the regex url.

Maybe i can somehow concatenate the proxy header to the `static_url`parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `xstatic_url`? Did you mean `static_url`?

Comment: Xstatic is another static folder with .js files. But the idea is the same as with the static_path which I want to be able to update on the fly.

Comment: You can subclass `StaticFileHandler` and override [`get_absolute_path`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler.get_absolute_path) and [`validate_absolute_path`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler.validate_absolute_path) methods.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to continue from the handler?
Let's say this is my custom Handler:
`[(r'/proxy/(.*)', ProxyFileHandler, {'path' : _STATIC_PATH_})]` 

what i want to achieve is something like this:

`class ProxyFileHandler(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):
    
def get(self, filename):
        
self.render("somepage.html", newStaticpath = MyProxyPath + _STATIC_PATH_)`

What exactly should i implement in the ovverrided methods:
`def get_absolute_path(cls, root, path)` and 
`def validate_absolute_path(self, root, absolute_path)`
how it will help my case?
thanks in advance.